# AWS Systems Manager Explorer data retrieve via CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-systems-manager

I'm trying to retrieve patch compliance data for AWS ec2 instances using **CLI or SDK** under below limitations.

- I need to retrieve **from the master account** for sub accounts ec2 instances(within AWS Organization)
- The instances has to be limited only to the accounts and regions that are configured in **"Quick Setup"** in Systems Manager.

**Tips ->**

- I need to retrieve whether the instances are compliant or non-compliant.
- I can do this accountwise using ssm:ListComplianceItems but my requirement is to retrieve all accounts details from the Master account.

**How to do in console ->**

- Navigate to Systems Manager console -> Explorer -> OpsData
- Apply the correct filter
- We can see all sub accounts compliance details.